# best practices for passing arguments to commands or macros

Tags: best-practices, latex3, xparse

I implemented some commands/macros recently and I'm thinking about reducing the
number of arguments given to a command/macro. Basically, until now I have created some
macros with `xparse` or `\cs_new:N` from latex3. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \foo {m}
{
    \str_new:N \l_my_word
    \str_set:Nn \l_my_word {#1}
    \twice{\l_my_word}

}

\cs_new:Npn \twice #1
{
    \str_use:N #1~\str_use:N #1
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document} 
    \foo{Hello}
\end{document}
```

If I understand right, here the "l" from `\l_my_word` is just a naming convention. I could also write the command `twice` in the following way:

```
\cs_new:Npn \twice
{
    \str_use:N \l_my_word~\str_use:N \l_my_word
}
```

If I know I will use the variable `\l_my_word` in the command `\twice` do I have to use
the first or the second version of the command ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You word the question as if the second form is going against the convention but that is not so `l_` prefix is the convention for names local to the current group (not to the current macro definition) so that is the case with both forms that you suggest as you used the local `set` command to define it.

So either form is fine, depending if you want to use `\twice` in other contexts.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few weaknesses in your code.

The main one is that `\str_new:N` should not go in the definition of `\foo`, but outside. With your code, calling `\foo` twice would result in an error.
Second, all names of variables should end with the variable type. Also, `\twice` should be an `expl3` function.

Here's a possible implementation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \foo {m}
{
    \str_set:Nn \l_lucarmand_word_str {#1}
    \lucarmand_twice_str:N \l_lucarmand_word_str
}
\str_new:N \l_lucarmand_word_str

\cs_new:Npn \lucarmand_twice_str:N #1
{
    \str_use:N #1~\str_use:N #1
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\foo{Hello}

\end{document}
```

However, the same task can be accomplished without setting string variables and even become fully expandable.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \foo {m}
 {
  \lucarmand_twice:e { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \lucarmand_twice:n
 {
  #1~#1
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \lucarmand_twice:n { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document} 

\foo{Hello}

\edef\test{\foo{Hello}}
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the weaknesses of my code. I'll need time to fully understand your second implementation. I know there is an alternative, thank you!